# Concurrency help on a custom queue-like data structure

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency

I am trying to implement an insertion-performance-focused, queue-like data structure that must meet the following requirements:

1. Must be thread-safe
2. Must be able to add to queue without synchronizing
3. Must be able to get a "snapshot" view of the queue

My issue is getting the 'snapshot' view in a way that doesn't require synchronization of the insert. Since I can block the removal and elements can only be added to the end, getting the elements shouldn't be an issue. The problem I keep running into is that the LinkedList's iterator has an unsupressable concurrent modification fast-fail baked in and 'LinkedList.get(int)' is O(n).

Below is a pared-down example of where I am with what should be a fairly simple task.

```
public class SnapshotableQueue<T> {
    private final LinkedList<T> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Object removeLock = new Object();

    public void add(T element) {
        queue.add(element);
    }

    public T remove() {
        synchronized(removeLock) {
            return queue.remove();
        }
    }

    public List<T> getSnapshot() {
        synchronized(removeLock) {
            int length = queue.size();
            List<T> snapshot = new ArrayList<>(length);

            ???

            return snapshot;
        }
    }
}
```

**Unacceptable Solution #1**

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    snapshot.add(snapshot.get(i));
```

'LinkedList.get(int)' is O(n)

**Unacceptable Solution #2**

```
Iterator<T> iterator = queue.iterator();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    snapshot.add(iterator.next());
```

Isn't thread-safe (throws ConcurrentModificationException)

**Unacceptable Solution #3**

```
Change queue to ArrayList
```

'ArrayList.remove(0)' is O(n)

Comment: NB: your code is not thread safe, you need a synchronized block for the method add too

Comment: this is probably the reason why you get the ConcurrentModificationException in solution #2

Comment: It actually is thread safe since I am only adding to the end and am synchronizing the remove.  Unfortunately, the LinkedList iterator has a "dumb" check for seeing if *anything* changes.  It would have been nice for the designers to provide a way to specify your own iterator that could have left off the training wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead of `LinkedList` then use the `iterator()` to build your snapshot which is natively thread safe.

Your method `getSnapshot` will then be simply

```
public List<T> getSnapshot() {
    return new ArrayList<>(queue);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend that too. It uses an algorithm with separate write and read locks based on http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf The link in the javadoc to that document on michaels user space is outdated X) It should provide thread safe and concurrent read and write access with high performance.

Comment: Awesome.  I had looked briefly at this when scanning the "java.util.concurrent" package, but for some reason I ended up passing over it.  Looked closer at the JavaDocs and a benchmarking blog https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/java-best-practices-queue-battle-and.html  Looks great.  Thanks for pointing me back the right way.

Comment: @doge this is a different story but if T is not thread safe and it is read and modify by several threads concurrently you will face indeed issues

Comment: This is what I am talking about. If class is not completely thread-safe it is not thread-safe. This issue must be considered too. Sharing not-thread-safe state can be achieved by deep-copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is this one in Java [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) it's part of the concurrent package and seems to do exactly what you want.

But mind that it creates a copy of the list every time you insert something, so it should only be used in scenarios were you read a lot more than you write.

Comment: I will be writing *way* more than reading, so this will not work for me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes that's right  CopyOnWriteArrayList  is only interesting when you mostly read and rarely write otherwise it is a perf killer